# Determine if a string is only numbers or a comma

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I determine if a string contains only numbers or a comma?

```
var x = '99,999,999';
var isMatch = x.match('/[\d|,]/');
```

The above always returns null.

Comment: Two points are missing in your post: the question and the tries.

Comment: @ChrisHardie Cool. Hope you find it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/^[\d,]+$/` Note that this will not tell you if the number is formatted correctly (i.e. `,99,` will be accepted just as `99` or `9,999`).

`/^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$|^\d+$)/` while more complex, this regex will test to see if the number is a properly formatted number (it won't accept `,`,`1,`,`,1`,`1111,`,`1,1,1` only `1`,`11`,`111`,`1,111`,`1111` etc.)

Comment: This will work but is quite awful. See @euantorano answer which is already better.

Answer (score 0):

To be a little more exact:

```
/^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$/
```

Only matches when the number is delimited by a comma after every 3rd digit from the right. (This doesn't account for decimals)

Comment: Also could be simplified like so: ([0-9]{3}) to match 3 digits in a row. Much cleaner.

Comment: fixed the single and 4 digit issue. was missing a "?". this was a typo. as far are 1,1,1 is concerned. I believe(though he wasn't clear) that the op wanted to match formatted numbers. not just any string containing numbers or commas.

Comment: `\d(\d\d?)?` can be simplified to `\d{1,3}`. Also, as @JanDvorak points out, `1,234` is rejected, but `1234,` is accepted.

Comment: I believe I've cleaned it up & fixed all issues reported

Comment: it still rejects `1,1,1`

Comment: as I stated: "I believe(though he wasn't clear) that the op wanted to match formatted numbers. not just any string containing numbers or commas."

Comment: Please note I didn't downvote (I won't upvote any of the answers either, though - there are already too many trivial regex questions)